exe_common.inl crash on my proxmox windows
Our team is developping a GUI software, and we recently acquired a dedicated server to automatically compile, test and deploy our software. However, while the compilation goes well, we're unable to run our software on the remote server.
The server is accessible via a VPN so all computers are effectively on LAN together (all of our local PCs and our servers running via proxmox are in a 192.168.0.0/16 subnet).
We're developping in C++, and are notably using Boost, QT, and OpenCascade libraries. We're compiling with Visual Studio 17 2022's MSVC. When running a simple Hello World program, it works.
Our server is running a Windows VM in ProxMox, configured with more than enough hardware for our needs. The windows version is the exact same on my local PC and on the remote server. Everything is up to date (especially drivers), Microsoft redistribuables are up to date and the software compiled from the remote can be run in local, but not on the remote.
At first, I suspected a mstsc (windows remote desktop access) issue with graphic drivers, but enabling it on my local PC and connecting from another PC on the virtual LAN network with my VPN IP let me run the software perfectly fine.
The software cannot run in debug, release, install, or in any way. It compiles fine, the software compiled on the remote can run in local, but not on the remote. The environment variable $LastExitCode indicates -1073741795, which seems to indicate file system error. When using Visual Studio debugging, the crash seems to happen in exe_common.inl, with the return instruction pointer on line 258.
EDIT When using assembly debugging in visual studio, it crashes on instruction vxorps xmm0,xmm0,xmm0 which apparently do not exists on very old processors, maybe that's the issue ?
EDIT
This instruction appears to only be available on recent CPUs (post 2015 for intel, post 2022 for AMD), and such processors are not working with our proxmox install. This is probably our culprit. Either our software somehow compiles on a CPU an instruction it cannot even perform, or one of our libraries that was compiled with this instruction (I'd say Boost, because the assembly file where it crashes is this one: boost::xpressive::detail::xpression_linker<char>::accept<struct boost::xpressive::detail::static_xpression<struct boost::xpressive::detail::posix_charset_matcher<struct boost::xpressive::cpp_regex_traits<char> >,struct boost::xpressive::detail::static_xpression<struct boost::xpressive::detail::true_matcher,struct boost::xpressive::detail::no_next> >,struct boost::mpl::bool_<1> >(struct boost::xpressive::detail::simple_repeat_matcher<struct boost::xpressive::detail::static_xpression<struct boost::xpressive::detail::posix_charset_matcher<struct boost::xpressive::cpp_regex_traits<char> >,struct boost::xpressive::detail::static_xpression<struct boost::xpressive::detail::true_matcher,struct boost::xpressive::detail::no_next> >,struct boost::mpl::bool_<1> > const &,void const *)).
I'm never sure if it means that the crash happened on the said line or on the previous line if it called a function, which is the case here, so here are the line just before the crash and the line of the crash.
256: _initterm(__xc_a, __xc_z);
258: __scrt_current_native_startup_state = __scrt_native_startup_state::initialized;
The error is : 0xC000001D: Illegal Instruction.
My best guess would be that the compiler somehow outputs an instruction that is specific to intel's processors (on which our local machines run), or somehow uses an instruction that is not handled by the virtual processor of the Windows VM.
Note that this looks close to my problem but it seems unadressed: Illegal Instruction in exe_common.inl
Do anyone have any idea or knowledge of similar problems with proxmox windows or with any virtual or even non intel processor (We don't have any AMDs at work to try out)?
Within our project, removing the Qt includes and calls, and using a simple Hello World in main.cpp/main compiles and run.
We also tried installing another clean Windows on another VM (in the same proxmox), and we face the exact same issue. We tried changing the virtual graphic card when driver issues when the main theory, with no success.
I managed to run some games (Factorio, ADOFI) to check if the graphics drivers were working properly. However, FreeCAD (that uses both OpenCascade and Qt like our software) crashes as well, although it might be another issue.
We're currently on our way to try out every options of processors within proxmox.
